# Changing Width and Height of a Node in Cocos2d JS

Tags: cocos2d-js, drawrectangle

I have a rectangle using `cc.drawRect()` method in cocos2d JS.
`cc.moveBy` or `cc.moveTo` change the position,but is there any method to change its width and height?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can see all the supported actions you can run in a node if you look at the [API docs](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/reference/html5-js/V3.3/index.html) and navigate to:

-cc.Class
--cc.Action

And look into the categories that lay there. In this case, you'll want to look into `cc.ScaleTo(duration, sx, sy)` to change the scale. There doesn't seem to be methods to alter width and height per se as actions in v3 (there will be in v4), so if that's definately what you want you should look into scheduling a function that changes those parameters.

PS: here's an [explanation of how actions work](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Actions), and here's how they [changed from prevoious versions in Cocos2D-JS](http://cocos2d-x.org/docs/manual/framework/html5/v3/cc-actions/en).